# Schedule Alarm Manager daily

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have some issues setting the Android AlarmManager to execute daily.
The user can set his specific time, and it should run daily on this time.
Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
            NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
            MainActivity.this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Make sure, there is no active Alarm
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    if(notificationEnabled) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);

        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, notificationHour);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, notificationMinute);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

Now I can't figure out, why this won't work. I once set the alarm to 10:05 and the Alarm fired in the evening. The alarm should fire each day at the specific time (if it's enabled only, of course). Starting with the current day. So if i set it to a few minutes or hours later, it should run also today, and every other day, until I cancel the alarm.#

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a wrong Unixtimestamp from Calender.

Try this

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);

// With setInexactRepeating(), you have to use one of the AlarmManager interval
// constants--in this case, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY.
alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

[From Android Trainigs Scheduling Repeating Alarms](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)